# Unable to Preview Laravel

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and tried everything as per this guide : http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/

I now have Laravel installed but cannot preview it when typing http://laravel.example.com in browser

It says, but I have 777 given to laravel folder in home.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at laravel.example.com Port 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be in right directory to be able to run php artisan command and you need to chmod that directory to have privileges on reading it

go to your project directory with cd /var/www/html/name of the project and run

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the latest/bleeding edge changes in Laravel? It looks like that tutorial wants you to pull the latest files from git, which may not be production-ready. Have you tried following the official instructions here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation?

Comment: Thanks. I have successfully installed Laravel. I used create project and I now have a Laravel working directory. Just that I cannot preview it. :(

Comment: Also, when use php artisan serve, it says

Could not open input file: artisan